Is there a way to COPY certain columns in binary format and others in text
I have an interesting use-case. I want to copy certain tables using the COPY command in PostgreSQL.
Specifically, I am constructing the COPY command wherein I want to use the binary format for the BYTEA columns alone.
In, my current approach I just construct the COPY command and use PGresult *res = PQexec(pgsql->connection, sql); (sql - is basically the COPY command either in text/binary format. ex - copy (SELECT %s FROM ONLY %s %s) WITH (FORMAT BINARY)).
Is there a way where I can use a few columns in text and others in binary with COPY?

No. Reading the docs would have told you that COPY: Binary Format The binary format option causes all data to be stored/read as binary format rather than as text..
